# How does one properly use the nautilus & command in a graphical SSH into debian 6.0.4?

Tags: ssh

```
Last login: Wed Mar 21 20:10:33 2012 from astrolab17.astro.washington.edu 
1 td% nautilus &
[1] 9847 
2 td% Initializing nautilus-gdu extension
```

And then I quit nautilus.

The thing is, though, that putting the & operator at the end of nautilus, I'm supposed to be able to enter new commands after I close (or 'X' out of) the nautilus window. This happens with most other programs like Matlab. Except that this doesn't happen with Debian.

The distribution involved is Debian 6.0.4.

Comment: There is `/etc/debian_version` file with Debian codename (version) in it.

Comment: So what goes wrong? What's the “this” that doesn't happen with Debian?

Comment: So as for what goes wrong - when I close the Nautilus window, it doesn't allow me to launch any new commands at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ... & disown

Some programs require that you use **& disown**.  Some programs will still put output to your terminal, which is hard to deal with, but you can try directing the output to **/dev/null**.

For example:

```
nautilus > /dev/null & disown
```

This will also prevent nautilus from closing if you close the terminal window.

#### ... ; bash

Is the terminal closing immediately when you launch nautilus?

```
nautilus > /dev/null & disown ; bash
```

#### CTRL+C

Are you *sure* you cannot run additional programs?  Try hitting **CTRL+C** to refresh your prompt.